# What does $X+Y$ being proportional to $Z_1 + Z_2$ mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

[image]

$1)$ Does $X$ and $Y$ each having standard gaussian distribution imply that their joint distribution will have standard gaussian?

$2)$What does $X+Y$ being proportional to $Z_1 + Z_2$ mean?

Comment: The usual meaning of proportional is that $X+Y=\lambda (Z_1+Z_2)$ for some $\lambda \in \Bbb R$

Comment: To your first question: No, since $X$ and $Y$ are correlated. Standard Gaussian distribution of a vector requires components to be independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) No. The joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ may not be even Gaussian. Take, for example, $X=v_1$ and $Y=|v_2|1\{v_1\ge 0\}-|v_2|1\{v_1< 0\}$, where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are independent standard normal r.v.s.

(2) Let $W:=(X,Y)^{\top}$ and $Z:=(Z_1,Z_2)^{\top}$. You are looking for a matrix $A$ s.t.
$$
W\overset{d}{=}AZ.
$$
Any such matrix $A$ must satisfy $\operatorname{Var}(W)=\operatorname{Var}(AZ)=AA^{\top}$. A straightforward candidate is $(\operatorname{Var}(W))^{1/2}$, i.e.
$$
\frac{1}{2}\times\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{1+\rho}+\sqrt{1-\rho} & \sqrt{1+\rho}-\sqrt{1-\rho} \\
\sqrt{1+\rho}-\sqrt{1-\rho} & \sqrt{1+\rho}+\sqrt{1-\rho}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
In particular, when $W=AZ$, $X+Y=\sqrt{1+\rho}\,(Z_1+Z_2)$.

Comment: Which steps did you take to calculate that matrix?

Comment: @ThePoorJew Check [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_2_by_2_matrix) or [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt+%7B%7B1%2C+r%7D%2C+%7Br%2C+1%7D%7D).